# Spring security: get password in UserDetailsServiceMethod

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

In order to get my account I have a external spring application that I need to login at. Why I need it is not important but in order to do a /login call on the API I need to get the password in the UserDetailsServiceMethod. Here is my security setup:

```
//https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

//Constructor gets authLogic for external authentication
@Autowired
public WebSecurity(@Qualifier("authLogic") UserDetailsService userDetailsService){
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources", "/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**", "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources/configuration/security").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilter(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .addFilter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
}

@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList(BANK_API, INVENTORY_API, MARKET_API)); //TODO: is dit correct??
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("X-Auth-Token","Authorization","Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"));

    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
}
```

My UserDetailsServiceMethod implementation:

```
@Service
public class AuthLogic implements UserDetailsService {
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    private IAccountRepository accountRepository;
    private RestCallLogic restCall;

    @Autowired
    public AuthLogic(HttpServletRequest request, IAccountRepository accountRepository, RestCallLogic restCall){
        this.request = request;
        this.accountRepository = accountRepository;
        this.restCall = restCall;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        //get password
        //make restcall to external login
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can get the password while using the spring security implementation. Because I could easily make my own class and do the login from there but it would be nice to use Spring security for it. Also the login returns a token that I can reform to a User. Maybe i'm just overthinking...

In order to make a API call i needed to write a custom AuthenticationProvider:

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

        String username = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        UserDetails principal = new User(username, password, new ArrayList<>());

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, password, new ArrayList<>());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: No you don't... You need a custom `AuthenticationProvider` not a custom `UserDetailsService`. You are trying to solve it in the wrong place.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information!!! The only problem I have know is that my custom AuthenticationProvider doesn't trigger when i do /login

Comment: But your `AuthenticatioNprovider` isn't calling anything? It only returns a user it doesn't do a call to an external system at all. Also I doubt that your `JwtAuthenticationFilter` is actually producing a `UsernamePasswordAuthentication`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a week I finally got what I wanted. So i made a custom authentication provider that will make a REST call to my authentication API. If the username and password I gave are correct I'll get a JWT-token back that contains a username, roles and a ID. after that I just call a custom Authentication service that checks if the user id already exists in its database. If that isn't the case than I'll create a new user with the given id from the JWT-token.

Here is my custom authentication provider:

```
public class JwtAuthenticationProvider extends AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider {

    //custom authentication service
    private AuthLogic userDetailsImpl;

    public JwtAuthenticationProvider(AuthLogic userDetailsImpl) {
        this.userDetailsImpl = userDetailsImpl;
    }

    @Override
    protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        //JWTUser is a custom class that extends the UserDetails class from spring
        JwtUser user = (JwtUser) userDetails;

        //call the custom auth service to check if the user exists in the database
        userDetailsImpl.loadUserByUsername(user.getUserID(), user.getUsername());
    }

    @Override
    protected UserDetails retrieveUser(String username, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        //get the token from a external authentication API
        String token = retrieveAccountData(new LoginWrapper(username, authentication.getCredentials().toString()));

        Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(JWTKEY)
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();

        List<String> scopes = (List<String>) claims.get("scopes");
        int UserId = (int) claims.get("userID");
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = scopes.stream()
                .map(authority -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        //return the User
        return new JwtUser(UserId, username, authentication.getCredentials().toString(), authorities);
    }

    private String retrieveAccountData(LoginWrapper loginWrapper){
        URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(BANK_LOGIN).build().toUri();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

        RequestEntity<String> request = RequestEntity
                .post(uri)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(gson.toJson(loginWrapper));

        //post call
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(request, String.class);

        //check if status code is correct
        if(response.getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.OK) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(loginWrapper.getUsername());
        }

        //convert to LoginWrapper
        return gson.fromJson(response.getBody(), TokenWrapper.class).getToken();
    }
}
```

And here is my custom authentication service:

```
@Service
public class AuthLogic {
    private IAccountRepository accountRepository;

    @Autowired
    public AuthLogic(IAccountRepository context) {
        this.accountRepository = context;
    }
trough with the jwt token)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(int userId, String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<Account> foundAccount = accountRepository.findById(userId);

        Account account;
        //check if user has logged in to our inventory API before, if not create new account
        if (!foundAccount.isPresent()) {
            account = accountRepository.save(new Account(userId, username));
        } else {
            account = foundAccount.get();
        }

        return new JwtUserPrincipal(account);
    }
}
```

In order to call the service from the provider you need to configure your WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter properly:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private JwtAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    public WebSecurity(@Qualifier("authLogic") AuthLogic userDetailsImpl) {
        this.authenticationProvider = new JwtAuthenticationProvider(userDetailsImpl);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }
}
```

I hope this answer helps.

Answer (score 2):

Behind the scene, Spring Security parses user's credentials in filter (ex. `BasicAuthenticationFilter`, `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` etc.  - the filters retrieves user credentials), if such filter successfully retrieved user's credentials it passes such credentials to `AuthenticationProvider` to verify credentials and create user's details ([read more about AuthenticationProvider](https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture/)). The `AuthenticationProvider` can verify credentials on various way.

One of the implementation of `AuthenticationProvider` is `DaoAuthenticationProvider` which tries to find user by username in `UserDetailsService` and if it found it gets `UserDetails` for the user from `UserDetailsService` and then checks if password provided by the user is satisfing the password in `UserDetails`.

In your case you need to make such request not in `UserDetailsService`, but in `AuthenticationProvider` because it's responsible for such case.

My suggestion is to extend `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider` class from spring security and implement your functionality in abstract method `protected abstract UserDetails retrieveUser(String username, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException;`.

For example:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConf43547 extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(new AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider() {
            @Override
            protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) throws AuthenticationException {
                //from docs: "[...]Generally a subclass will at least compare the 
                //Authentication.getCredentials() with a UserDetails.getPassword() [...]"
            }

            @Override
            protected UserDetails retrieveUser(String s, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) throws AuthenticationException {
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.getCredentials();
                //your api here
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The better example: look how `DaoAuthenticationProvider` extends `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider` in spring security.

Comment: Do i have to do any other configurations in the WebSecurityConfigureAdapter. Cause I started making a custom AuthenticationProvider class and it doesn't get triggered when I do /login it just says Acces Denied.

Comment: One more question: where do i put my call to the database to check if the account exists in my local database?